Integral of Normal and Poisson Process
I'm trying to find the percentile function of a random variable
$$Y=e^{-at+b_1\sqrt{t}Z+N_t(\mu+\sigma^2Z)}+\int_0^te^{a\cdot s+b\cdot \sqrt{t-s}Z+(N_t-N_s-1)\cdot[c+g\cdot Z]}ds, $$
where $a, b_1, \mu, \sigma, b, c, g$ are constants, $Z\sim N(0,1)$ and $N_t$ is a Poisson process.
My plan is to find the distribution of both variables and to then use convolution to find the distribution of the sum, however, both terms seem to be tripping me up. Admittedly, I've spent more time looking at the integral term.
I have tried to solve the integral but the best i can do is approximate it using discrete time intervals and using the arrival time formulation of a Poisson process and simply calculate the integral as the area under the Poisson. Ideally I want to find the distribution function for this. I was thinking about using Ito's Lemma for but i think this would be quite complicated...
I have also tried changing variables of the integral using $y=t-s$ which reduces the Poisson to $N_y-1$ but the integral remains and I can't seem to find a solution.
Any help and suggestions would be appreciated!
